# How to disable redirects for a specific page in a Wicket application?

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have one page in my application which needs to preserve the original URL without redirecting. The reason is because there is a hashmark which has important information after it, and this is lost during a redirect for Safari on OS X.

I know I can do this to disable all redirect for my entire application:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy( IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER );
```

Is there some way to preserve the regular behavior with buffered rendering, but use the one pass rendering for a specific page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1)** `requestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(page), RedirectPolicy.NEVER))`
Use it instead of `setResponsePage(Page/Class)`

---

**Approach 2)** Provide your own `IPageRenderer` and never redirect for this specific page
See `Application#setPageRendererProvider`. Extend from `WebPageRenderer` to save you some troubles.

Example code which disables redirect for a `NoRedirectTest` page:

```
setPageRendererProvider( new IPageRendererProvider() {
    public IPageRenderer get( final RenderPageRequestHandler context ) {
        return new WebPageRenderer( context ) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isOnePassRender() {
                IRequestablePage whichPage = getRenderPageRequestHandler().getPage();
                return whichPage instanceof NoRedirectTest || super.isOnePassRender();
            }
        };
    }
} );
```

Comment: This is a bookmarkable page from an external JavaScript redirect, would I be able to use your suggestion in that scenario?

Comment: For a bookmarkable page, where in my code does this go? It doesn't seem like it belongs in the constructor, and I wouldn't put it in any of my action handlers since it's a bookmarkable page.

Comment: The page is being accessed from an external JavaScript redirect, not from my application.